# sending email from app do domain different from com

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im facing problem that whne I try to send email it is sent only when user in inc com domain. For example gmail.com or mailinator.com

In other cases email is never received. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It is here chance, that your Mail server block this messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the DNS that you server calls is faulty. Check if other domains resolve correctly, i.e. using

```
System.Net.IPHostEntry host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("noncom.de");
if(host.AddressList.Length > 0)
    Response.Write(host.AddressList[0].ToString());
else
    Response.Write("Nope");
```

Answer (score 1):

badly designed mail sending library doing buggy regular expression checks against email addresses, e.g.

```
if ! match(email_addr, "@\w+\.com$")
```

otherwise the domain name should be properly extracted from email address, mx records resolved and mail sent thru MTA if any valid MX record is found for the domain.

more infos would help us in giving you a proper answer. like the name of the library you're using, if any. or the piece of code your using to send emails. or the email address(es) the sending is failing for.